# Angular4, In ng2 dragulla, draggable element is dragged through out the page.how to enable drag event on specific panel

Tags: angular, draggable, ng2-dragula

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nBxb.png)

I am using ng2 dragula. Its working fine, but when I drag element to any 
other location its dragging the element. Technically it should not. How to 
stop dragging element to any other panel/place
please provide solution
Thanks In advance.
This is my code .html

```
//app.module.ts
import { DragulaModule } from 'ng2-dragula';

imports: [
    DragulaModule
]

<ul class="edit-metrics-lists list-group table-scroll" 
  [dragula]='"bag-one"' 
  [dragulaModel]='selectedMetrics' 
  style="height: 224px;
         overflow-y: auto;
         margin-bottom: 0; 
         margin-top: -10px;">
    <li class="list-group-item" 
      *ngFor="let item of selectedMetrics" 
      style="padding-left: 0px;">
        <img src="./assets/img/drag.small.inactive.png" style="display:inline-block">
        <span style="padding-left: 6px;">{{item.metricName}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please show more of your html template; Where/How are you declaring the dragular directive?

Comment: <ul class="edit-metrics-lists list-group table-scroll" [dragula]='"bag-one"' [dragulaModel]='selectedMetrics' style="height: 224px; overflow-y: auto; margin-bottom: 0; margin-top: -10px;">
                <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let item of selectedMetrics" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                  <img src="./assets/img/drag.small.inactive.png" style="display:inline-block">
                  <span style="padding-left: 6px;">{{item.metricName}}</span>
                </li>
              </ul>

Comment: "Its working fine, but when I drag element to any other location its dragging the element. Technically it should not." The purpose of this library is not to drag-and-drop elements? Can you share the code with Fiddle or Plunker  and explain the problem concretely.

Comment: please find attached screenshot

Comment: it should drop only to the panel which have list but its droppping to any location.

Comment: The code you have provided should work as expected, I suspect your issue is somewhere else in your code. You will be able to drop the item anywhere within the `[dragula]='"bag-one"'` that you have declared. Are you maybe not declaring that again?